# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. : dataTable Server-side processing using SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php, sql, datatable, xampp, sqlsrv

I was able to implement this tutorial in my test page: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/joinSelf.

My problem is I cannot implement this example in my other test page? https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html.

What seems to be the problem?

What's the difference between the configuration for dataTable editor and standard dataTable connection via Server-Side?

I am using **SQL SERVER 2012**, **XAMPP**, and **SQLSRV** for connection.

This is what I'm getting.

> DataTables warning: table id=example - An error occurred while connecting to the database. The error reported by the server was: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

It should work since I only need to populate these lines, right?

```
// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'xx',
    'pass' => 'xxxxx',
    'db'   => 'xxxxx',
    'host' => 'xxxxx\SQLSERVER'
);
```

Similar to what I did to the dataTable Editor, I only populated this line.

```
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Database user / pass
 */
$sql_details = array(
    "type" => "Sqlserver",     // Database type: "Mysql", "Postgres", "Sqlserver", "Sqlite" or "Oracle"
    "user" => "xx",          // Database user name
    "pass" => "xxxxx",          // Database password
    "host" => "xxxxx\SQLSERVER", // Database host
    "port" => "",          // Database connection port (can be left empty for default)
    "db"   => "xxxxx",          // Database name
    "dsn"  => "",          // PHP DSN extra information. Set as `charset=utf8mb4` if you are using MySQL
    "pdoAttr" => array()   // PHP PDO attributes array. See the PHP documentation for all options
);
```

I also have the `require( 'ssp.class.php' );` available in server-side scripts since what I downloaded was a full example.

May I ask for your help regarding this matter?